# Selecionar Linha do DBGrid e o StringGrid reconhecer o NUMERO da linha

Tags: delphi

Vocês saberiam me dizer se há a possibilidade quando eu selecionar uma linha do `DBGrid`, o meu `StringGrid` apenas reconhecer qual linha eu selecionei?

Não estou fazendo funções: apenas estou realizando este tipo de coisa para informação para o usuário, ou seja, meu `DBGrid` tem **2000 registros encontrados**, e meu `StringGrid` também, porém, no `DBGrid` tem os registros do banco de dados, e o `StringGrid` de outro arquivo. Tudo que eu preciso é que na hora que selecionar o registro, na respectiva linha o `StringGrid` reconheça qual linha eu selecionei e vá até ela, sem eu precisar procurar.

Para ser mais claro, quero que em algum evento, de acordo com a execução do sistema, quando eu selecionar uma determinada linha do `DBGrid`, o `StringGrid` reconheça e vá para a linha respectiva do `DBGrid`.

Como fazer?

Comment: Você falou de `StringList` e `StringGrid`. Qual deles é o certo, afinal? E o que os preenche? Existe relação entre um registro mostrado no `DBGrid` e uma linha deste outro grid ou lista?

Comment: Então @AlexSC, eu falei `StringList` primeiro, mas errei, como editei ali em cima, agora é `StringGrid`. Teria como ajudar?

Comment: Você quer que, quando eu selecionar a linha 1000 do `DBGrid`, a linha 1000 do `TStringGrid` seja selecionada ou que ao selecionar uma linha do `DBGrid` o sistema busque um "par" no `TStringGrid`? Edite sua pergunta para deixa-la mais clara por favor

Comment: Poderia mostrar um pouco de código? Só um pequeno exemplo do que precisa, provavelmente dentro do evento clique.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, exatamente isto, eu editei minha pergunta.

Comment: Exatamente o que? Dei duas hipoteses, 1 ou 2? :)

Comment: @Math, cara não digo um código, por que nao consigo pensar em nenhum, não conheço m bm a estrutura do DBGrid, quanto a do StringGrid, tenho certeza tem relação ao código : `StringGrid1.Row`, tentei igualhar com as rows do DBGrid, mas desconheço a opção.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca EHAUEHAUHEAUHEAUHE, Desculpa cara, é uma correria que li a primeira apenas. Então, é a primeira msm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro defina a seguinte opção no seu DBGrid:

```
dgrowselect := True;
```

[image: dgrowselect]

Depois, o seu `DBGrid` possui um `DataSource` e este está ligado a um DataSet (seja este uma `Query`, `ClientDataset`, o que for). Este possui um índice.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso abaixo o índice é `dbgOFD.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo`

Com este índice você altera o seguinte trecho de código:

```pascal
StringGrid1.Col :=0;
StringGrid1.Row :=1; //dbgOFD.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo - 1
StringGrid1.Selection:=TGridRect(Rect(0,1 ,MaxInt ,1));
StringGrid1.SetFocus;
```

*Obs.: Note que o `StringGrid` deve ter **pelo menos** a mesma quantidade de linhas do `DBGrid`. Caso não tenha, você vai ter que tratar a exceção.*

Comment: posso colocar o código no FormActivate? ou tem um evento específico para colocar o código?

Comment: Penso que o ideal seria no `OnColEnter` ou no `OnCellClick` do `DBGrid`.

Comment: beleza, vou testar agora msm, outra perguntinha, no caso do dataset, eu utilizaria o código comentado né?

Comment: Exatamente. Uma variável dele, dependendo do tipo de dataset.

Comment: Estou utilizando uma Query mesmo, utilizarei esse msm código que está apontando acima, por enquanto não esta selecionando nada pois minha query ta dando problema em relação a entrada de datas (Conversao) T.T

Comment: obrigado cara! Deu certíssimo!